# jTextField.getText() in a different class

Tags: java, swing, csv, jtextfield

I am trying to write a CSV file from Class B. However, the jTextField (which is in class A) just isn't outputting to the created CSV file. I need help/steps/tips on this.

EDIT: This now complies.

Class A

```
public class ClassA extends javax.swing.JFrame {
public ClassA() {
   initComponents();
}
private void initComponents() {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    jTextField1 = new JTextField();
    JMenu aFile = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem saveFile = new JMenuItem ("Save...");
    menuBar.add(aFile);
    aFile.add(saveFile);
    saveFile.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClassB ss = new ClassB(); 
        try {
            ss.saveAsTable();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
    });
}
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
        new ClassA().setVisible(true);
    }
   });
}
protected static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
}
```

Class B

```
public class ClassB extends ClassA{
    /**
     * 
     */

    public ClassB() {}

    public void saveAsTable() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser sat = new JFileChooser();
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
            "CSV files (*csv)", "csv");
    sat.setFileFilter(filter);
    int ret = sat.showSaveDialog(null);
    if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File f = sat.getSelectedFile();
    FileWriter out = new FileWriter(f);
    out.write(jTextField1.getText() + ",");//This doesn't work...
    out.close();

}
}
```

Comment: your code even compile, try to post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) for better help.

Comment: I don't see your code compiling. Especially ClassA.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that requires help quickly.  As it is specific to a particular moment in time, it is not of interest to a wider audience and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the problem is not that it "doesn't work". The problem is that you can't even make the code compile. If so, start by reading, trying to understand, trying again, googling the exact error message(s) you get from the compiler. Then, if you're still stuck, post the compiler error message in your question, because this message is intended to be read, and tells precisely what the error is, and where it is. Ignoring error messages won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: The code actually works (well except this JTextField), it's just that I modified it so it wouldn't be a WHOLE page of code. I made errors while I was trimming it down for this site. I fixed it now (so it at least complies and does something).

Comment: It still doesn't compile. `jTextField1` is not declared anywhere in ClassB.

Comment: It complies, I just double checked with eclipse. The only thing I removed was the import libraries.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I missed the ClassB extends ClassA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never add your `jtextfield1`  to your frame, by the way your inheritance it's extremely dangerous.

In some part in the ClassA constructor add this line.

```
this.add(jtextField1);
```

You are creating in `actionPerformed` another `ClassA`

```
saveFile.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener(){

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ClassB ss = new ClassB(); 
        try {
            ss.saveAsTable();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
    });
```

This is happening cause  `ss` it's a `ClassB` and for that is a `Class A`, so this code.

Comment: You have to add the textfield to some `Container` :S , if not you never can't text something to it.. Your inheritance has no sense at all.. and why textfield is static? I would redesign your object model..

Comment: I was trying out ways that's why it was on static. It wasn't originally on static, it's because the code for some reason my code refuses to write out the text that is found in jTextField1. I can input 2000 characters in that field for all I care, and while saving to a CSV file it doesn't read what's in jTextField1, just outputs nothing.

Comment: if is not static, then the jextfield1 is another one that you are modifying... if i were you  i would change my class model design.. class b extends class a for some reason?

Comment: I did it so Class B has access to all variables from Class A as long they are protected.

Answer (score -1):

Explain this in more detail please, then someone/i might be able to help you.

Edit: It is hard to see what EXACTLY you are trying to do but, if you need to save of open a file, check out `JFileChooser` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html)
Edit2: Putting text from the texfield into a string: `String yourtext = JTextField1.getText();`

Comment: Don't post comments as answers.

Comment: Sorry, i am going to try and fix this mess, based on the little info he has given us. Will add code in an edit soon.

Comment: Let's say jTextField1 has some text in it. I want to save it. Go through the process of File > Save > Save the file. However nothing comes out.

Comment: Well a FileChooser is what you want for saving files. but first you need to sort out the errors in your code. You want to put the text of the text field into a string, ill dd how to do than in the answer.

Comment: By the way I tried that, still didn't work. I forgot to mention this a while ago when I saw this.